# Observing selectedObjects in NSArrayController always returns <null>

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, key-value-observing, appkit

I don't understand KVO. Really. I have a document based application. In Document `awakeFromNib` I added:

```
invoicesController.addObserver(
        self,
        forKeyPath: "selectedObjects",
        options: [.old, .new],
        context: &invoicesControllerSelectedObjectsChangedContext)
```

Next, in document `observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)` I try to determine `old` and `new` selections. Dictionary which comes with `change` has both keys, but their values are always `<null>`. I've tried `selection` and `selectionIndexes` as an observed value and nothing happened — `change` has always `<null>` values. `print(change)` prints:

```
change Optional([__C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: kind): 1, __C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: old): <null>, __C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: new): <null>])
```

Is it a normal behaviour? How to get old  and new selected objects?

Comment: how to understand it? Do not use KVO? no Notifications, no observe at all?

Comment: This is a known bug see [NSArrayController arrangedObjects KVO](https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2014/Apr/msg00160.html) and [NSArrayController and KVO dependent keys](http://ddeville.me/2013/10/nsarraycontroller-and-kvo-dependent-keys).